# Ubuntu 16.04.1 refuses to boot from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation

My 32-bit desktop has been successfully running on Ubuntu 14.04 for the past two years.

Recently, before upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.1, I decided to try it first. Finding the official installer too slow, I downloaded the torrent version of `ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386` from the "Alternative downloads" provided in the official Ubuntu site, and created a start-up USB with the Start-up Disk Creator. But every time I tried to boot from it, I failed and received an error message like :

```
Missing parameter in configuration file...gfxboot.32: not a COM32 image
```

I checked whether the machine could boot from the live USB containing Ubuntu 14.04; it could. I doubted the data integrity of the ISO file downloaded through torrent. So I decided to go for the slower official download, and created the Start-up disk with it.

However, when I tried to boot from it, I got the same error message. Can anyone give me a clue to what is happening and how to get around the problem? My experience naturally discourages me about Ubuntu 16.04.1. Is anyone else having the same experience with it? My research in the forum doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: The checksums and digital signature are provided. They can be found at http://releases.ubuntu.com/. I got this piece of information from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes.

Comment: But those are probably meant for checking data integrity. That doesn't seem to be my problem. Anyway, Sujeet Sinha's suggestion (see below) has worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you receive the warning message, you'll notice the cursor blinking as well. It's waiting for you to provide a command.

If you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can see the list of valid commands or you can simply type `live`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your live OS should boot!

I faced this issue myself but later realized it's some sort of a bug that's been reported and worked upon. You can see the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1325801).

Comment: I have just tried the "live Enter" method. It took a while, and I was worried, but it worked. Shall try the other method later. Meanwhile, please advise me whether I should postpone upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.1 till the bug has been worked upon and eliminated? Another thing: you may consider posting your solutions in the "Answer Your Question" form. Many will likely benefit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could go and proceed with installing the OS.. I have been using it myself without any issues. Another thing with the bug is the issue is not with the OS but with the Startup Disk Creator..

Comment: The problem being with the Startup Disk Creator is probably unlikely. For, as I wrote, it works fine with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I haven't yet installed it. Since you installed it in spite of facing the same problem while trying, and since it's been a while, I'll be grateful to know your experience with it. If you haven't had any problems in all this time, I think I too will go ahead and install it. After all, this version promises a lot of improvements.

Comment: Since you installed it despite facing the same problem at the stage of trying it, and since it's been a while, could you please let me know your experience with it? If you haven't had any problems, I think I too will go ahead and install it.

Comment: No problems whatsoever, you should definitely go ahead and install it..